# Angular binding for a property that will change only once

Tags: angularjs

Two way binding is cool when the bound variable can change often, but there are cases where the variable won't change after getting assigned, or will only change once.

Is there a way to tell angular that a binding won't be needed to get monitored anymore for changes after being assigned, or after changing just 1 time?

(for angular 1.x)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah they introduced (think it was in 1.4) the `{{::}}` binding, so for example:

```
<p>{{::ctrl.text}}</p>
```

Will only be bound once.
More details can be found in the [documentation for bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) under "One-Time binding"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AngularJS 1.3 and above

You can use feature called [one-time](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) binding

*Syntax:*

{{::myVar}}

From Docs

```
An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value
```

You can further read about it [here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/).

If you are using 1.2 and earlier 
You can use [BindOnce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce).

Answer (score 1):

While a one-time binding is what you're looking for, I suspect the real reasoning behind your question is performance:

`ng-bind` is actually still faster than a one-time binding.

[Source](https://ng-perf.com/tag/ng-perf/#post-35)